# Trouble with data type on hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have return value on database like this:

> 0.0000000000003277436483677620725942937943099205123581

But everytime i want to call on hibernate, i get return only :

> 3.27743648367762072594293794309920512358E-13

Right now I am using String to get value from database. But, I need to return data like this :

> .0000000000003277436483677620725942937943099205123581

without using 0 in first number.

What type of variable should I use in hibernate? And how can I return the value without using 0 in the first number?

Comment: where's the problem? that's just two different formats to display the same number. Well, except for  the missing 1 at the end of the second value.

Comment: Hibernate returns the value correctly. The value is of exponent -13 is basically 3.2774... x 10 ^ -13.

Comment: @Paul all i need is, i want to get the same value from oracle into hibernate. My oracle return data `0.0000000000003277436483677620725942937943099205123581` but, hibernate return `3.27743648367762072594293794309920512358`. I don't care with the last number, all i need is the hibernate must to return data from 0.000000000000 like database return

Comment: @BuhakeSindi i need the datatype of hibernate can return 0.000000000000 like database return, i don't really care with the last number

Comment: @user3505775 it does. You don't quite get what `E-13` means, do you? Short version: `E-13` is equivalent to `* 10 ^ (-13)`. The problem isn't what the database returns, but how you display it.

Comment: @paul oh ya, you are right. i forget about E-13. But, if i use String, absolutely, the data don't get E-13 means. Can you tell me, what the correct data type that i must to use?

Comment: @user3505775 as I said before: that has absolutely nothing to do with  the data-type. The reason for the two values to be displayed differently is the format that is applied. Can't quite tell what format you use, but most likely the default one. Just use a different format

Comment: @user3505775 The data is **correct**. The exponent value is there for readability purpose. This is **not** how the data was returned but how the data is formatted. The value is equal on both Hibernate and Oracle. You can format the value in the front-end *however* you like.